# Workflow for a Github fork with compatible and incompatible changes

Tags: git, github, branching

I've forked a Github repo and added an `upstream` remote as described [here](https://gist.github.com/Chaser324/ce0505fbed06b947d962).  I expect to make some backward-compatible bug fixes for which I'd like to submit upstream pull requests, as well as some major non-backward-compatible changes.  This question is about how to manage both of those things in one repo, or whether that's even a good idea.  I've described what I intend to do below.  I'm very new to working with Git branches, so please tell me whether this makes sense.

**Backward-compatible changes**

I think I should keep `origin/master` synced with `upstream/master` and never merge any changes of my own into this branch.  I'll create feature branches off `origin/master` for any changes that I expect to submit upstream.  If they're accepted, I'll merge `upstream/master` into `origin/master` and delete the branches.

**Non-backward-compatible changes**

I think I should create a separate branch off `origin/master` to aggregate all my own changes.  This branch would be called `origin/my-version` or something like that.  I would merge my backward-compatible branches into this branch without waiting for them to be accepted upstream.  I would work on non-backward-compatible changes in branches of `my-version`.  Whenever I merge upstream changes into `origin/master`, I'd rebase `my-version` on the new `origin/master HEAD`.  I don't expect a lot of merge conflicts because the upstream project is mature and development is slow.

My main doubt is whether merging my backward-compatible branches into `my-version` will create problems if those changes are later accepted upstream and I merge them into `origin/master`.  What effect would this have on rebasing `my-version`, if indeed rebasing is what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

Create one branch for you to work in for your non-breaking changes, this should be branched from `origin/master`.

Create another branch for your breaking changes. This branch should conceptually inherit from your non-breaking changes branch, which inherits from `origin/master`

Never merge from your breaking branch to your non-breaking branch, and never merge from your non-breaking branch to `origin/master`

This way, you always do your non-breaking bug-fixes in a version which is able to cleanly pull from the original codebase, and any merge conflicts that happen due to your breaking changes will *always* happen in your breaking-changes branch, where you can fix them without leaking code to upstream.

As for submitting your pull requests to merge your non-breaking changes upstream, create a repo on your **own** github account where you push your non-breaking branch (fully merged with `origin/master`), and submit a pull request from that repo to the upstream repo.

Quick diagram:

```
origin/master (pull only) -> non-breaking changes (pull only) -> breaking changes (merge conflicts happen here)
```

Never push up the chain, never merge up the chain.